# Does NRefactory understand WinRT language projections?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, icsharpcode, nrefactory

Does NRefactory understand WinRT language projection from C#? If not then what would be the easiest way to add this functionality to NRefactory?

The following unit test seems to indicate that it does not currently support it. Resolving `Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.Languages[0]` should resolve to System.String, but this fails. My theory is that the resolver expects to find an indexer, but there isn't one because it is actually a project of `IVector.GetAt(...)`.

To reproduce this issue, clone NRefactory, and add the file `ICSharpCode.NRefactory.Tests\CSharp\Resolver\WinrtTests.cs`:

```
using ICSharpCode.NRefactory.TypeSystem;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.Resolver
{
    public class WinrtTests : ResolverTestBase
    {
        public override void SetUp()
        {
            var loader = new CecilLoader();
            project = new CSharpProjectContent().AddAssemblyReferences(new [] {
                CecilLoaderTests.Mscorlib,
                loader.LoadAssemblyFile(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Windows.winmd")
            });
            compilation = project.CreateCompilation();
        }

        [Test]
        public void FixedStatement()
        {
            const string program =
                @"class TestClass
                {
                    static void Main()
                    {
                        var i = $Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.Languages[0]$;
                    }
                }";

            var rr = Resolve(program);
            Assert.AreEqual("System.String", rr.Type.FullName);
        }
    }
}
```